# Dynamically select database based on session

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am using JPA and WildFly 10.

Imagine that two different companies each have subscriptions to use my application. Ideally, I'd like to split up the data of the two companies into separate databases, or at the very least, separately prefixed tables, using JPA. If a user logs in on http://example.com/company1/, it will seem as though the application is completely separate from the application running at http://example.com/company2/, when in actuality, the "two" applications are part of one application.

Multiple users may be logged in at the same time from different companies, so the database being used should be session based.

The main reason for splitting up the data into separate tables or databases is for better organization. The reason for using one application rather than multiple is to allow for horizontal scaling.

I have seen answers which state to create multiple `persistence.xml` files, however my application should dynamically create and drop the databases or tables based on the current subscriptions that are active. Think of it like a web hosting company, where as soon as you pay, you can login and begin working on your website; that's the direction I am moving in. Therefore, I cannot hard-code the different companies into the program.

How can this be done with JPA? Is it even possible? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make your application multi tenant capable. One way I know is:

- use a field in every database table which contains a predefined value for a tenant.
- set current tenant when the request comes from this tenant
- then use Hibernate filtering capability to filter tenant-specific data automatically. Once the filter is activated every query will return only data specific to the current tenant.

Note: a Hibernate filter is set on the Hibernate `Session` object. If you are using pure JPA, the Entity Manager interface has a method called `getDelegate()` which returns a Hibernate session object.

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/de-DE/html/filters.html) is a link to the information about Hibernate filters. There are also tutorials on how to use them on the Internet.

Comment: FWIW _"If you are using pure JPA, ... getDelegate() returns a HIbernate session"_ ... which in turn means you are tied to a JPA provider.

Comment: @NeilStockton You are right. It is provider specific extension. JPA does not have built-in filtering capability. If you have a better solution I would like to know it too.

Comment: @ujulu What do you think of this? https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/jpa-multitenancy/

Comment: I'm gonna try it and will post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge This is not a better solution. Imagine your database structure is the same (e.g. the same table structure for all tenants). Then when you want to make changes to your schema you have to add those changes to all of the schemas and so on. That will be a real headache. I had this solution in a project and we had to switch to the filter solution.

Comment: @ujulu I didn't think of that. Would queries become slower over time if everyone's data is all together than if it was separated by schema, though? It also seems a bit riskier having everyone's data all together. If some nasty bug wiped it out it'd be gone for everyone

Comment: @MitchTalmadge The size of the data can impact the performance. But database systems have optimizers if you use them correctly. `If some nasty bug wiped it out it'd be gone for everyone`: that can happen. But you have to have a backup for your data for such cases.